# LocalStorage.getItem: Check if a key exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

First I'm setting the string value after user login in login.html page:

```
success:function(data){
        if(res.IsSuccess){      
             localStorage.setItem("token",data.Response.AuthToken);
             window.location.href="/dashboard.html";
        }
 } Once this is success it is redirecting to dashboard
```

On the dashboard page, I'm retrieving the value like this:

`var Authtoken=localStorage.getItem("token")`

How to check if the **Authtoken** value exists or not?

More explanation:

I'm storing the localStorage value from the server response, so in Serverend the authtoken expire time is 10min.

1. [Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob3gf.png)
   once the user click on *RememberMe*, at the time only I'm storing textbox values using localstorage to redirect to the dashboard next time without login(BrowserAction Icon click)
2. Once I click the login button I'm storing the authtoken `localStorage.setItem("token",data.Response.AuthToken);`

If the dashboard based on localStorage value, how to check if it exists or not?

Comment: It will return null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `if(localStorage.getItem('token')) { \\found } else { \\Not exist }`

Comment: How to check, if it is exist or not???

Comment: repeating the question won't get different answer,..  If the answers given are not what you want, you need to explain in more detail what it is your really after.

Comment: If you are calling `localStorage.getItem('not_existing_key')` with a key which is not existing in `localStorage`, it will return `null` value.

Comment: Hi @HassanImam the localStorage.getItem('token') expire date is 10min,
After 10 min what will be the output

Comment: If your code doesn't clear the localStorage, then you will still receive the `token` value.

Comment: What expire date are you talking about?, locale storage has not expiry date.

Comment: @Hassan Imam, i'm not clear any localStorage

Comment: You need to probably implement some server side logic for expiring token after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it like to make sure you get something out of it

```
var token = localStorage.getItem("token")
var data = token && JSON.parse(token)
```